# What are other meanings of the word "song"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can the word "song" mean story and news?

I'm reading Clash of Kings and I noticed that characters use the word song even when they're not talking about music.

Comment: This would fit better on English Language and Usage (ELL); we don't generally answer language-specific questions here.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Same type: The "real" title of *Game of Thrones* is "A Song of Fire and Ice". In this context, a song is indeed a (long) story. This appears in other languages as well, e.g. there is a well-known German poem titled "Das Lied von der Glocke" (The Song of the Bell), which is but never sung to a melody. Nevertheless, reciting (long) stories (as a way of non-written information tradition, say) is easier if they rhyme and perhaps even easier if you enforce the meter by means of a melody. That's perhaps how you may consider the two concepts connected.

Comment: cf. Song of Roland.

Comment: The phrase _song and dance,_ often modified by _(same) (old)_, means a frequent and annoying sales pitch or political policy statement. _He's just giving us the same old song and dance; pay no attention._

Comment: The Song of Songs, which is Solomon's.  KJV Bible

Comment: @JohnLawler In BE "song and dance" is a fuss, and nothing else.

Comment: The example should be given in the text of the question, not in the comments.  Comments can vanish without notice.

Answer (score 2):

*Song* has an archaic meaning of "poem". The OED says:

> A combination of words and music sung with or without instrumental
> accompaniment; a composition, typically relatively short, consisting
> of lyrics, melody, and usually other elements of musical arrangement,
> (sometimes) esp. a poem set to music; (hence also) an instrumental
> piece or passage having structural or other characteristics suggestive
> of a song. **Also occasionally: a poem, esp. one in rhymed stanzas,
> resembling a song.** (emphasis added)

So, no, it doesn't mean "story", or "news"; but it can refer to a story which is told in verse.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the word "song" mean story and news?

In some contexts - but you give no context...

OED

> **To change one's song** (idiom) -> to change one's statement, attitude, or position.
>
> 1913   G. B. McCutcheon Fool & his Money 214   *You've changed your song, my friend. A few weeks ago you were saying he ought to pay it.*